# Passing React Navigation to Child of Child Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I'm dynamically building my "screen" with the use of child "row" and "button" components. I'm only using this method because I can't find a flex-flow property available for react-native.

So basically I'm mapping through an array of arrays to build each row, and within the row, mapping through each array to build each button. Because the onPress needs to be set in the button, I'm passing the URL for each
`onPress{() => this.props.navigation.navigate({navigationURL})`

as a prop, first to the row, and then to the button. The problem is I keep getting the error `'Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined`. I'm sure this is because only the actual "screens" within the navigator have access to the navigation props. I've also tried passing

```
navigation={this.props.navigation}
```

but had no success. I've looked through all of the documentation and can't seem to find anything helpful. Anyone else encountered a similar situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access the `navigation` object from a component which is not part of `navigator`, then wrap that component in `withNavigation` HOC. Within the wrapped component you can access navigation using `this.props.navigation`. Take a look at the [official document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html)

**Sample**

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
...
class CustomButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Button title="Back" onPress={() => { 
      this.props.navigation.goBack() }} />;
    }
}

export default withNavigation(CustomButton);
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried that and still having difficulty. Do I need to wrap both the child row component and it's child the button component with wrapNavigation?

Comment: As per the document, you need to wrap only the component where you will be using `navigation`. BTW what error you are getting now?

Comment: if you are accessing `navigation` using `this.props.navigation` and getting error `Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined`, this means `this.props` is undefined, this should not be the case as `props` is always available to the component. BTW is `this` referencing to the component, have u used `arrow function` or `bind` the function with `this`? Can you share the code where you are accessing `this.props.navigation`

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh, silly mistake. I wasn't setting up Props in the constructor. Thank you [Prasun Pal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3186640/prasun-pal) for the help! Here's my code if someone else has an issue.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
    import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation'



    class ButtonName extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {};
          }

        render() {
            return (

                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PageName')}
                >
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }
    }

    export default withNavigation(ButtonName);
```